# Why SQL subquery doesn't work inside SUM function?

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

I'm learning SQL, and the lesson is subquery. My query is:

```
select sum (select tientra from thang7_8714 where tientra > 0) as tmp;
```

But Postgres notice me the message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select" LINE 1: select sum (select
  tientra from thang7_8714 where tientra > ...
  SQL state: 42601 Character: 13
```

I know i can get the result without subquery, but i'm trying to practice with it, so i use subquery inside `SUM` function but couldn't.

Please help me understanding SQL subquery.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In general, you cannot pass a subquery as an argument to an aggregation functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you explain why subquery cannot be argument of aggregate functions?

Comment: . . Because that is how SQL is defined.  Probably because only a scalar subquery would be allowed in that context, and aggregation functions are not particularly useful on a single value.  Some databases might support the construct, under some circumstances, though.

Answer (score 2):

### SUM with a subquery

`SUM` wants one parameter. This can be a fixed value (e.g. 123) or a column (e.g. mycolumn) or an expression (e.g. 123 * mycolumn) or a subquery. But this subquery would have to be scalar, which means it returns only one value.

A subquery is surrounded by parentheses, so such `SUM` with a subquery would look like this:

```
select sum( (select t2.value from t2 where t2.id = t1.id_t1) )
from t1;
```

But subqueries inside aggregate functions are extremely rare, because we can achieve the same with a join (e.g. `select sum(t2.value) from t1 join t2 on t2.id = t1.id_t2;`).

### Typical places for subqueries:

### SELECT

```
select col1, col2, (<scalar subquery>) from ...
```

The subquery must be scalar here if course.

### FROM

```
select t.col1, sq.col2 from t join (<subquery>) sq on ...
```

Here the subquery is often an aggregation query, e.g.

```
select a.x, bagg.total
from a 
join 
(
  select y, sum(value) as total
  from b
  group by y
) bagg on bagg.y = a.x;
```

### IN / EXISTS

```
select * from t join where colx in (<subquery>);
```

An `EXISTS` subquery is usually correlated with the main query, i.e. references columns from the main query:

```
select * from a join where exists (select * from b where b.x = a.y);
```

And an `IN` clause is usually not correlated:

```
select * from a join where a.y in (select b.x from b);
```

Comment: sorry for my stupid question, just newbie in SQL. Is that a scalar subquery? "select sum ((select sum (tientra) from thang7_8714))" because the query work. So the scalar subquery is inside double parentheses? And your example query "select sum( (select t2.value from t2 where t2.id = t1.id_t1) )
from t1;" is scarlar subquery because it returns one value?

Comment: Yes, this is a scalar subquery. You select only one value, i.e. only one column (`sum(tientra)`) and only one row (because you aggregate with `SUM` and have no `GROUP BY`). My example, too, selects only one value, i.e. one column (`t2.value`) and one row (because a table's ID should be unique and I use `where t2.id = ...`). Of course, your query doesn't make too much sense. In your subquery you select a sum, say 123. Then in your main query you sum up all values, and as it's just one value, you get the same sum (the sum of 123 is 123).

Comment: As to double parentheses: Every subquery starts and ends with a parenthesis. This is one pair. The other pair belongs to `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, SQL does not allow aggregation functions to have arguments that are subqueries.  The generic solution is to move the aggregation *inside* the subquery:

```
select (select sum(tientra) from thang7_8714 where tientra > 0) as tmp;
```

Presumably, you know that the more canonical method for solving this is:

```
select sum(tientra) as tmp
from thang7_8714
where tientra > 0;
```